# Multiple extensions Chromium not working after update to 13.10

Tags: chromium, 13.10

It seems like after updating to Ubuntu 13.10 and Chromium 29.0 multiple extensions have stopped working. Reddit Enhancement Suite and Smoothscroll are among them. Some extensions partially work, like Adblock. Others, like Webtimer and Collusion still work as they did before.

I realize this might be slightly off topic if the problem lies with the new version of Chromium. However, it may very well be something about the new version of Ubuntu, or perhaps a bit of both.

Comment: I don't understand this downvote; at least give me a reason why or some constructive criticism. I don't mind this question closing because it's off topic but it's not an inherently *bad* question.

Comment: Ah I didn't see that, thanks. Still, my question should be marked as a duplicate then, not downvoted.